# Is there a way to specific the google cloud platform project for kubectl in the command?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there something like: 
kubectl get pods --project=PROJECT_ID

I would like not to modify my default gcloud configuration to switch between my staging and production environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`kubectl` saves clusters/contexts in its configuration. If you use the default scripts to bring up the cluster, these entries should've been set for your clutser.

A brief overview of `kubectl config`:

- [`kubectl config view`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_view/) let you to view the cluster/contexts in
  your configuration.
- [`kubectl config set-cluster`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-cluster/) and [`kubectl config set-context`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-context/) modifies/adds new entries.

You can use [`kubectl config use-context`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_use-context/) to change the default context, and `kubectl --context=CONTEXT get pods` to switch to a different context for the current command.

Answer (score 16):

You can download credentials for each of your clusters using `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` which takes the `--project` flag. Once the credentials are cached locally, you can use the `--context` flag (as Yu-Ju explains in her answer) to switch between clusters for each command.

Comment: Somehow `kubectl` was using wrong user after several different attempts. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me

```
gcloud container clusters list
```

then

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials \
--zone <LOCATION> <NAME>
```

LOCATION and NAME are the columns provided by the previous command. E.g.

```
NAME                  LOCATION    MASTER_VERSION    MASTER_IP       MACHINE_TYPE  NODE_VERSION      NUM_NODES  STATUS
```